Generate FMOV without inline assembly
I want to:

Move a 64-bit value from GPR to the lower 64-bits of a vector register
Do an operation (specifically bdep or bext)
Move the lower 64-bits of my vector register to a GPR

This doesn't seem to be possible using ACLE intrinsics.
This is the closest I can get using intrinsics: https://godbolt.org/z/brjG6fe38
    const auto vec = svbdep_u64(svdup_n_u64(a), svdup_n_u64(b));
    return svlastb_u64(svptrue_b64(), vec);

which Clang compiles to
foo(unsigned long, unsigned long):
        mov     z0.d, x0
        ptrue   p0.d
        mov     z1.d, x1
        bdep    z0.d, z0.d, z1.d
        lastb   x0, p0, z0.d
        ret

The compiler is able to replace dup with mov, which is great. However, it still generates lastb, which is completely wasteful since I only need the last 64 bits. An fmov would do just fine.
Am I missing something, or is this basic operation not supported by ACLE intrinsics?

Have you tried masking only required bits or chaning return type of your function. It may seam vastefull, but even then generated code may have other advantages or execution time may be similar anyway, microbenchmark may be usefull to tell difference using inline assembly?

I agree that I don't see a way to do it with intrinsics.  It's easy to get with inline asm though: asm("fmov %0, %d1" : "=r" (ret) : "w" (vec));

It'd be nice if one could do asm("" : "=w" (ret) : "0" (vec)) but clang complains that ret and vec are of the wrong types.

GNU C native vector syntax allows indexing a vector with [].
return vec[0] compiles to fmov.  I don't know SVE very well, and I haven't checked how Clang's <arm_sve.h> defines the vector types.
This is unlikely to be portable to other compilers, especially MSVC.
uint64_t foo(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    const auto vec = svbdep_u64(svdup_n_u64(a), svdup_n_u64(b));
    return vec[0];
}

Godbolt:
foo(unsigned long, unsigned long):
        mov     z0.d, x0
        mov     z1.d, x1
        bdep    z0.d, z0.d, z1.d
        fmov    x0, d0
        ret


Nice! This works for both gcc and clang!

Btw, I filed an issue and cited your answer: https://github.com/ARM-software/acle/issues/374
